# Explode block, modify its subentities, and Redefining the Block in VBA/ActiveX

Tags: vb.net, activex, autocad

I open a dwg file through visual studio 2010 vb-net (VBA/ActiveX)
In the drawing, I use an AcadSelectionSet to select an existing block which contains a line and a text.
I explode the block, I get the text object, I change its text value, (it appears on CAD screen) and I try unsuccessfully to redefine a new block through the existing unchanged and changed objects. Any help ?

```
        Dim ssetObj As AcadSelectionSet
        On Error Resume Next
        ssetObj = acadApp.Documents.Application.ActiveDocument.SelectionSets.Add("MySet")
        ssetObj.Clear()
        Dim FilterType(0) As Int16
        Dim FilterData(0) As Object
        FilterType(0) = 8
        FilterData(0) = "C_Cell"
        ssetObj.Select(AcSelect.acSelectionSetAll, , , FilterType, FilterData)
        MsgBox(ssetObj.Count)
        ' EXPLOSION
        Dim ExplodedObj As Object
        Dim SelectedBlockReference As AcadBlockReference
        Dim SelectionSet As AcadSelectionSet
        Dim BOMPieceMarkRef As String
        Dim BOMPieceMarkID As String
        Dim TheLayer As String
        SelectionSet = ssetObj
        SelectedBlockReference = ssetObj(0)
        ExplodedObj = SelectedBlockReference.Explode
        Dim Pieces(UBound(ExplodedObj)) As Object
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To UBound(ExplodedObj)
            Pieces(i) = ExplodedObj(i)
            If ExplodedObj(i).EntityName = "AcDbMText" Then
                BOMPieceMarkRef = ExplodedObj(i).TextString
                BOMPieceMarkID = ExplodedObj(i).Hyperlinks.Item(0).URL
                Dim Handle = ExplodedObj(i).Item(ExplodedObj.Handle)
                Dim LayerName = ExplodedObj(i).Layer
                ExplodedObj(i).TextString() = "\H1x;\W1.05;KERAIA_New"
                ' RECREATE THE NEW BLOCK
                Dim NewblockObj As AcadBlock
                ' HELP HERE !!!!
            End If
            ExplodedObj(i).Update()
        Next
```

Comment: You do not need to explode a block reference to redefine a block definition. You should directly act on the entities within the block definition (AcadBlock) which is an item of the block table (AcadBlocks) of the drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example directly acting on the block definition. It's written in C#, but easily convertible to VB.

```
        AcadBlock block = acadApp.ActiveDocument.Blocks.Item(blockName);
        foreach (AcadEntity entity in block)
        {
            if (entity.EntityName == "AcDbMText")
            {
                AcadMText mtext = (AcadMText)entity;
                mtext.TextString = "\\H1x;\\W1.05;KERAIA_New";
            }
        }
        acadApp.ActiveDocument.Regen(AcRegenType.acActiveViewport);
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot !
Bibliography writes, explode change and rebild.
Recomment me a book

Comment: But mtext.Alignment = AcAlignment.acAlignmentRight not work
while mtext.color = AcColor.acCyan works.
Why ?

Comment: The [AcadMText](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-2532B20E-413D-4F59-9E88-B40E8AABB9FF) do not have an Alignment property. Use `mtext.AttachmentPoint` instead.